# Why is 1.0 / 3.0 * 3.0 exactly 1 in IEEE floating point representation?

Tags: floating-point

According to this [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/39789/164922) I know that `1.0 / 3.0` can not be precisely represented in IEEE floating point format, but instead is rounded to a IEEE floating point number slightly less than 1/3, with the mantissa being a truncated part of the real number, as the picture below:
[image]

My question is why is `1.0 / 3.0 * 3.0` would produce exact 1. I've tried it in both Lua and C++ with the same result, which I assume is what IEEE standard defines. Shouldn't the result be a floating number with its mantissa all 1s, because I suppose there's no rounding happening in the second multiplication operation?

Comment: To explore, try `1./49*49`. 49 is the first integer for which this does not produce 1 in the binary64 format.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Very interesting. I first tried just printing `1./49*49` in C++, looks like the printed result is still 1. But if compared within program with 1.0, they indeed are different. Makes me wonder how the print functions might have treated these floating numbers very near to an integer.

Comment: In some languages, the various methods for converting floating-point data to numerals produce some fixed number of digits, and they round to the destination format. E.g., in C, `printf("%e", x);` produces six digits after the decimal point. This will not distinguish 1 from values near 1, since not enough digits are shown.  In some languages, the default is to produce enough digits to uniquely distinguish the value from other values representable in the format. The latter has gained some popularity since good algorithms for it became available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's rounding happening in the multiplication. In the default "round-to-nearest-even" mode, the final result rounds to the exact value of `1`, since it's the closest representable value.

You can change the rounding mode to see the result you want like this:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fenv.h>

#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

int main(void) {

  double a = 1;
  double b = 3;
  double ab = a/b;

  printf("Default rounding (RNE)  : %lf\n", ab*b);

  fesetround(FE_TOWARDZERO);

  printf("Round towards zero (RTZ): %lf\n", ab*b);

  return 0;
};
```

When I run this program, I get:

```
Default rounding (RNE)  : 1.000000
Round towards zero (RTZ): 0.999999
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm stupid, why would I think there would not be a rounding for the multiplication operation (I wrongly assumed the `* 3.0` part would be done precisely as with an integer 3).

Answer (score 1):

It just so happens that the rounding error in the multiplication cancels out the rounding error in the division.

To be ultra-precise, `1.0 / 3.0` is represented in IEEE 754 double-precision as 6004799503160661 × 2<sup>-54</sup> = 1/3 - 1/(2<sup>54</sup> × 3).  Multiplying that exact result by 3 gives 1 - 2<sup>-54</sup>.  In binary, that's 0.111...111, with 54 1's after the radix point.  But since `double` has only 53 bits of significand, this value must be rounded.  And in the default rounding mode, it rounds *up* to exactly 1.0.

This fortuitous exact result from `1.0/x*x` doesn't always happen though.  As @EricPostpischil pointed out in a comment, `1.0/49.0*49.0` gives 1 - 2<sup>-53</sup>, not 1.